# Rails and MongoDB with MongoMapper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongomapper

I'm new to Rails development and I'm starting with MongoDB also.

I have been following this [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/75-complex-forms-part-3) tutorial about complex forms with Rails but I'm using MongoDB as my database. I'm having no problems inserting documents with it's childs and retrieving the data to the edit form, but when I try to update it I get this error

> undefined method `assert_valid_keys' for false:FalseClass

this is my entity class

```
class Project 
  include MongoMapper::Document

  key :name, String, :required => true
  key :priority, Integer

  many :tasks
  after_update :save_tasks

  def task_attributes=(task_attributes)
    task_attributes.each do |attributes|
    if attributes[:id].blank?
      tasks.build(attributes)
    else
      task = tasks.detect { |t| t.id.to_s == attributes[:id].to_s }  
      task.attributes = attributes
    end
  end    
end

def save_tasks
tasks.each do |t|
  if t.should_destroy?
    t.destroy
  else
    t.save(:validate => false)
  end
end
```

end
    end

```
class Task 
include MongoMapper::EmbeddedDocument

key :project_id, ObjectId
key :name, String
key :description, String
key :completed, Boolean

belongs_to :project
attr_accessor :should_destroy

def should_destroy?
  should_destroy.to_i == 1
end 
end
```

Does anyone knows whats happening here? Thanks

Comment: Ah, in this case, I think you *don't* want an explicit project_id in the Task class, because it's already handled by being embedded.

Comment: Oh, `save(false)` is what's failing. With mongomapper, you need to pass a hash of values to save. Do `save(:validate => false)` if you don't want to validate.

Comment: Thanks! but it worked partially, it only updates the existing elements and even add new ones, but it's not deleting and I get this error always

"stack level too deep"

Comment: How are you doing the delete? Could you make a pastie or gist of the full stacktrace?

Comment: Sorry at that time I hadn't added the code to be able to delete an existing task for a project, I have added it now and it seems it still doesn't work, here's the gist for the full Trace http://gist.github.com/402373
and I even uploaded the project to github for if anyone can help me :)
http://github.com/fcastellanos/rails_mongodb
very much appreciate your help

Comment: That stack trace is from the update action, not destroy. How are you doing the delete?

Comment: Sorry, I'm doing it from the save_task function, I updated both the Task and Project models

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed the Task entity from EmbeddedDocument to Document, and deleted the 
validates_associated: task from Project, it's now working updating, adding and 
deleting tasks from updating a Project.

Thanks a lot to x1a4 and John Nunemaker for the help :-)

Answer (score 2):

What does your Task class look like? Does it use EmbeddedDocument? If not, did you declare a key for project_id in it?

update - it's due to the `save(false)`, do `save(:validate => false)` and you should be set.

Comment: Dude thanks a lot for the quickness of your answers, I already deleted the project_id in the Task class but it throws the same error, any other ideas?